# Identifier 'x' has already been declared Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

A simple form to submit search result

```
<form>

    <label for="searchTerm">Search Term</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>

</form>
```

in main.js

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
//adding listener to form 
form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitted);
```

I am getting two errors ?

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'form' has already been declared**

Comment: please tell us how did you arrange the code in html?

Comment: got my silly error @kai thanks for early response

Comment: First issue might be because you are capturing form before the dom is ready. Second one because you already have a variable/constant declared. With the code you provided there is nothing wrong, we need more context

Answer (score 0):

With `document.querySelector()` it is best to use an element id **`#someId`** or a class specifier **`.someClass`**, or even a combination of both. See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

As for why it complains about `form`: it apparantly is defined already elsewhere, just pick a more unique name, or wrap your code in a function and then call that function.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#theForm");
console.log("form: " + form);

const input = document.querySelector("#searchTerm");
form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitted);

function formSubmitted() {
  //...
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <label for="searchTerm">Search Term</label>
  <input type="text" id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks peter but the error was something else

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake : i had imported  same main file twice in same file

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```